# Is the delayed differential equation with constant delays linear or nonlinear?

Tags: delay-differential-equations

Let us consider the following delayed differential equation

$\ddot{y}(t) + 2\dot{y}(t) + 4y = 2\dot{u}(t-\theta) + 4u(t-\theta)$

Here, $y$ is the output, $u$ is the input and $\theta$ denotes the time delay.

How can we mathematically prove if this equation is linear or nonlinear using superposition principle ?

Comment: It is linear as the dependent variables appear linearly. Superposition is a result of linearity and not the other way around.

Comment: How can we prove the linearity mathematically using superposition principle?